# RSpec - undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I have just begun chapter 10, gone through just after the Figure 10.1.

I have tried rake db:reset before my migrate and test:prepare commands, but that has not worked.

Here is my error, I could not find a similar one on here:

Failures:

```
1) Micropost 
     Failure/Error: @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user_id)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fcfecc789b8>
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Micropost 
     Failure/Error: @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user_id)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fcfecc8a000>
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00389 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:15 # Micropost 
rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:14 # Micropost
```

Here is my code:

for the file: **db/migrate/[my unique timestamp]_create_microposts.rb**

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]

  end
end
```

For file: **spec/models/micropost_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do
  # pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    #This code is not correct, idiomatically
   @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user_id)
  end

  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }

end
```

PS all my tests were green going into ch. 10

Comment: I need to tell you important thing regarding the TITLE of any question is that you shouldn't write it like this, please be specific with you issues and know whats you problem or what is causing you problem..I have seen two post of your and in both of them you have the same title, this can be accepted once but please keep this in mind.

Comment: I improved the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact code from [the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-initial_micropost_spec):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    # This code is not idiomatically correct.
    @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)
  end

  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
end
```

it's not `user_id: user_id` but `user_id: user.id`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
   @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user_id)
```

is wrong?  Where is user_id (the second mention, i.e. the value) coming from?

Perhaps `user.user_id` or `current_user.id`